# How can I send multiple documents to Elasticsearch datastream using Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to index a large number of documents in Python to Elasticsearch, after reading the documentation, they refer to [this example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/examples/bulk-ingest/bulk-ingest.py). (edit: I am using this exact code, only changed the index name into a datastream.)

This example works great when I am indexing into a normal index, however, when I try to index into a datastream, even into a brand new datastream, that can accept dynamic content, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Downloads/elasticsearch-py-main/examples/bulk-ingest/bulk-ingest.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Downloads/elasticsearch-py-main/examples/bulk-ingest/bulk-ingest.py", line 102, in main
    for ok, action in bulk(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 524, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 438, in streaming_bulk
    for data, (ok, info) in zip(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 355, in _process_bulk_chunk
    yield from gen
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 274, in _process_bulk_chunk_success
    raise BulkIndexError(f"{len(errors)} document(s) failed to index.", errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: 2 document(s) failed to index.
```

I cannot find any information on this, how can I index my data in bulk using the Elasticsearch Python connector?

Comment: can you share your code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated to clarify I am using the exact code in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because when sending documents to a data stream you need to set the action to `create` instead of `index`

```
{ "create": {"_id": "123"}}
{ "field": "value" }
```

With the [Python bulk helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.1/helpers.html#bulk-helpers), you need to explicitly set `'_op_type': 'create'` in your bulk actions.

Comment: This works, I simply added ```doc['_op_type'] = 'create'``` to the document before yielding it, and now it works.